# How to group sets by similarity in contained elements

Tags: python, set, similarity

I am using Python 2.7. I have routes which are composed of arrays of nodes that connect to each other. The nodes are identified by a string key, but for ease I will use numbers:

```
sample_route = [1,2,3,4,7] 
#obviously over-simplified; real things would be about 20-40 elements long
```

I will create a `set` made up of tuple pairs of point connections using zip, which will end up like:

```
set([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,7)])
```

I will need a way to filter out some routes that are very similar (like one or two added nodes) and use the minimal route out of those near-duplicates. My plan right now is to:

Start with the first (probably optimal) route. Iterate through the rest of the routes, and use the following formula to calculate its similarity to the sequence in step 1:

```
matching = len(value1.difference(value2)) + len(value2.difference(value1))
#value1, value2 = two compared sets
```

The lower the number, the more similar.
But **what is a good way to group the routes based on their similarity to other routes?** They will all be different lengths. I have never taken a statistics course.

**Example:**

```
sets = [
  set([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,10)]),
  set([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,6),(6,5),(5,10)]),
  set([(1,7),(7,3),(3,8),(8,7),(7,6),(6,5),(5,10)]),
  set([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,6),(6,5),(5,10)]),
  set([(1,9),(9,4),(4,5),(5,10)]),
  set([(1,9),(9,4),(4,6),(6,5),(5,10)])
]
```

In this example, the groupings may be something like `[[1,2,4],[3],[5,6]]`, where 1, 2, and 4 are very similar, 5 and 6 are similar, and 3 is nowhere near any of the others. 1 to 2 would have a score of 2, and 3 to 6 would have a score of 8, as examples. This is the sort of data I am using (though these are easy to read simplifications).

There is a time benefit in this. If I can remove redundant routes, I will trim off a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Is "similarity" what you mean, or is it closer to "contains?"

Comment: please define "similarity"

Comment: I do not have statistical education beyond the rudimentary. Could you please give a short summary of the distinction between "similarity" and "contains"?

Comment: I just modified the title of my question to hopefully clarify whatever David Ehrmann is wondering about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking into the networkx package.  It allows you to create directed graphs such as you are describing.  For measuring the similarity of 2 routes, I would recommend the Jaccard similarity index.  Here is code showing the example you illustrated.

First, import a few libraries: graphs, plotting, and numeric python. Then build the directed graph by adding nodes numbered 1 to 8.  Build the connections from node to node to build your path.  The networkx package has built-in capability to find all paths in the graph from one node to another: `nx.all_simple_paths(g, start_node, end_node)`.

Once you have all of the paths, you can compute the a matrix, `J`, of the Jaccard similarity between the paths.  How you actually want to cluster the paths by their similarity is up to you.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(range(1,8))
g.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,7)]) #path 1,2,3,4,7
g.add_edges_from([(4,5),(5,7)])             #path 1,2,3,4,5,7
g.add_edges_from([(4,6),(6,7)])             #path 1,2,3,4,6,7
paths_iter = nx.all_simple_paths(g,1,7)
paths = [p for p in paths]

np.random.seed(100000)
nx.draw_spring(g, with_labels=True)
plt.show()

def jaccard(v1, v2):
    return (len(np.intersect1d(v1,v2))+0.0)/len(np.union1d(v1,v2))

J = np.zeros([len(paths),len(paths)])
for i in range(J.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i, J.shape[1]):
        J[i,j] = J[j,i] = jaccard(paths[i],paths[j])

print J

> [[ 1.          0.71428571  0.83333333]
>  [ 0.71428571  1.          0.83333333]
>  [ 0.83333333  0.83333333  1.        ]]
```

[image: graph paths]

**EDIT**
Since you have a metric to compare the similarity of the paths to each other, look into k-means clustering to cluster the paths together.

`from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2`

I don't have enough of your code or your data to help anymore from this point.

Comment: I appreciate your answer including a library that could simplify the comparisons. However, this does not answer my question of how to actually group them. As stated, I know how to compare them, but not actually group them. I would prefer an answer using as much pure Python as possible. I already have classes with networking capability.

Comment: Since I do not have any clue about how to implement `kmeans2` with the data I have, I will ask a separate question about that.