# Common distance between two routes in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a question on Google maps API.

Assume we have two travellers traveller1 and traveller2. traveller1 wants to go from A to B, and traveller2 from C to D.

```
Route1: A --> a --> b --> c --> d --> B
Route2: C --> e --> b --> c --> d --> f --> D
```

Is there a way to find out the common distance between the above routes Route1 and Route2 ? by effect i mean the distance of sub route,

```
b--> c --> d
```

is it possible to find such distance through Google maps API ? I tried looking at various Google API such as Directions API, DistanceMatrix API, Roads API etc. But could not find anything.

Any way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't an API that will do that for you.  If you have both routes from a common directions service, you should be able to find the points in common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first use the Google Maps Directions API to get your steps from A to B and from C to D. Which should be `response.routes[0].legs[0].steps`.

Then you can compare the 2 paths to check which are the "common distance".

I created a quick demo showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/sb6sdj3r/1/

Answer (score 2):

There is not an API for this. But there are some simple algorithms you could make yourself.

Maybe make an array of connections from nodes, formatted like `Route1 = [[a,b],[b,c],[c,d]]`, and so on for `Route2`. Then you can iterate through both, and find commonalities:

```
var common = [];
for(var i=0; i<Route1.length; i++){
  for(var j=0; j<Route2.length; j++){
    if(Route1[i] == Route2[j]){
      common.push(Route1[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

This example here returns only the edges between the nodes. But you could extend this yourself if you wanted to find larger chunks of routes (instead of `[[b,c],[c,d]]`, you could find a way to join them and make `[b,c,d]`)

As kaho said, the Google Directions API returns steps. These can be formatted to what you need by using routes[0].legs[0].steps[i].end_location, .start_location, and parsing them into these connections.

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813923/how-to-group-sets-by-similarity-in-contained-elements) recently, about similarity and so on.